# How to edit cart item in Mageto 2 REST API?

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api

> How to edit cart item in Magento 2 REST API ?

I am adding product in cart using below API.

```
http://magento.host/index.php/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization Bearer <customer token>`

**Body**

---

```
{
    "item_id": 7,
    "sku": "MH11-S-Red",
    "qty": 8,
    "name": "Grayson Crewneck Sweatshirt ",
    "price": 64,
    "product_type": "configurable",
    "quote_id": "3",
    "product_option": {
        "extension_attributes": {
            "configurable_item_options": [
                {
                    "option_id": "93",
                    "option_value": 58
                },
                {
                    "option_id": "141",
                    "option_value": 168
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**How to EDIT this CART ITEM (Like `Qty`, `Attribute options` etc.)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **How to edit cart item in Mageto 2 REST API** ?

```
http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/items/{item_id}
```

- `method : **PUT**`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`

**BODY**

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "MH11",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "3",
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": 58
          },
          {
            "option_id": "141",
            "option_value": 168
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

**FROM HERE WE CAN EDIT CART ITEM (Like `Qty`, `Attribute options` etc.)**

Comment: This is working fine for me- for simple and configure products.

Comment: price is not set/update using this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284948/magento-2-unable-to-set-custom-price-in-cart-item-by-api

Answer (score 3):

Refer this:

1. For edit attribute options ->  **Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/UpdateItemOptions**
2. For edit qty -> **Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/UpdatePost**

Implement this two controller action to your Rest API Model file.

Comment: controller action ?

Comment: Bro i need REST API

Comment: Anyway thanks for the answer and i got the solution :) check my answer and +1 for your efforts.