# Magento 2 Unable to set custom Price in cart item by API

Tags: magento2, product, cart, api, quoteitem

I'm trying to add an item by API.every thing are working except item price
It's Magento Bug that not take price from API

https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#operation/quoteCartItemRepositoryV1SavePost

**POST** : `V1/carts/mine/items?cart_id=27333`

**Payload** :

```
{
"cartItem": 
    {
        "sku": "1024P270PDTS",
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 20,
        "quote_id": "27333"
    }
}
```

It will add item correctly but not the price it will not take a price from API it set price from magento.
How can I add product in cart with price 20 as passed in API

Even facing same problem with update item API it is not change API price which is sent in payload
**PUT** : `V1/carts/mine/items/105287?cart_id=27333`

```
{
"cartItem": 
    {
        "sku": "1024P270PDTS",
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 20,
        "quote_id": "27333",
        "item_id" : 105287
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `original_custom_price` index for change the price?

Comment: there is no fiels in api original_custom_price

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22215

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have same problem and i have solved it by Custom API
first create Qoute and update item price by item id saperately.

Add code in `webapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/carts/updateCartItem/:cartId/:itemId/:price" method="PUT">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\CartManagementInterface" method="updateCartItem"/>
            <resources>
                <resource ref="Magento_Cart::manage"/>
            </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**add logic in file**

```
public function updateCartItem($cartId,$itemId,$price) {

        if($price){
            //$quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
            $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($cartId);
            $quoteItem = $quote->getItemById($itemId);
            $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
            $quoteItem->setName($price);
            $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $quoteItem->save();
            $quote->save();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: it's not update cart items price

Comment: it update quote item you have to call API for update item and all done

Comment: dont change parameter/value when you call update cart item API

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not a bug, it's how it should be.
So you, as a customer, want to add stuff to the cart but set your own price on the item? Something does not add up.

If this is allowed, what would stop every customer from adding to the cart products and setting the price to 1 cent? Or even zero?

Anyway, if you really want this (I strongly advice against it), you can intervene somewhere int eh flow of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::addProduct()`

Comment: I just want it in API not every where,ANyway i'm not able to retrive that price sent in API.

Comment: Api is just a wrapper for the models that handle the web interface add to cart.

Comment: is there any way to update cart item price through API,As we can update price from admin while ordering by set custom price

Comment: By default there isn't. For the reason I stated above. If a customer finds this out, he/she can buy everything for free. In the backend is possible because it is assumed that the admin doing the order knows what he/she is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue where I needed to set a custom price for a product using the Magento 2 REST API. To accomplish this, I utilized a plugin to override the **save** function of the **\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister** class.

*Please keep in mind that modifying prices through the API can have security implications, and it's important to implement appropriate security measures and validate the input to ensure that only authorized and validated requests are processed.*

**Vendor\ModuleName\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister">
        <plugin name="cart_item_persister_around_save_item"
                type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\CartItemPersisterPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\CartItemPersisterPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemOptionsProcessor;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister;

class CartItemPersisterPlugin
{
    private ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository;
    private CartItemOptionsProcessor $cartItemOptionProcessor;

    /**
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param CartItemOptionsProcessor $cartItemOptionProcessor
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        CartItemOptionsProcessor $cartItemOptionProcessor
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->cartItemOptionProcessor = $cartItemOptionProcessor;
    }

    public function aroundSave(
        CartItemPersister $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        CartInterface $quote,
        CartItemInterface $item
    ): CartItemInterface {
        if (!$item->getPrice()) {
            return $proceed($quote, $item);
        }

        /** @var Quote $quote */
        $qty = $item->getQty();
        $price = $item->getPrice();
        if (!is_numeric($qty) || $qty <= 0) {
            throw InputException::invalidFieldValue('qty', $qty);
        }
        $cartId = $item->getQuoteId();
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        try {
            /** Update existing item */
            if (isset($itemId)) {
                $currentItem = $quote->getItemById($itemId);
                if (!$currentItem) {
                    throw new NoSuchEntityException(
                        __('The %1 Cart doesn\'t contain the %2 item.', $cartId, $itemId)
                    );
                }
                $productType = $currentItem->getProduct()->getTypeId();
                $buyRequestData = $this->cartItemOptionProcessor->getBuyRequest($productType, $item);
                if (is_object($buyRequestData)) {
                    /** Update item product options */
                    if ($currentItem->getQty() !== $buyRequestData->getQty()) {
                        $item = $quote->updateItem($itemId, $buyRequestData);
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($item->getQty() !== $currentItem->getQty()) {
                        $currentItem->clearMessage();
                        $currentItem->setQty($qty);
                        /**
                         * Qty validation errors are stored as items message
                         * @see \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator::validate
                         */
                        if (!empty($currentItem->getMessage()) && $currentItem->getHasError()) {
                            throw new LocalizedException(__($currentItem->getMessage()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                /** add new item to shopping cart */
                $product = $this->productRepository->get($item->getSku());
                $productType = $product->getTypeId();
                $item = $quote->addProduct(
                    $product,
                    $this->cartItemOptionProcessor->getBuyRequest($productType, $item)
                );
                if (is_string($item)) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(__($item));
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw $e;
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            throw $e;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__("The quote couldn't be saved."));
        }
        $itemId = $item->getId();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
            /** @var Item $quoteItem */
            if ($itemId == $quoteItem->getId()) {
                $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price)->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                $quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                $item = $this->cartItemOptionProcessor->addProductOptions($productType, $quoteItem);
                return $this->cartItemOptionProcessor->applyCustomOptions($item);
            }
        }
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(__("The quote couldn't be saved."));
    }
}
```

***Note: The code highlighted in gray is the code added to the original save function.***

> [image]
>
> [image]